# How can i send many videos from list in telebot python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

So I was writing a python script using telebot and got an error

```
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. 
Description: Bad Request: file must be non-empty
```

I have tried different methods from many forums, but nothing helps

```
import telebot

import random

import time

token = #token here

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

shit = ["C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\3wZ3.gif.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\65216814_456719028224290_7745639790787166208_n.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\doc_2022-03-10_16-41-49.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\doc_2022-03-10_16-42-04.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\doc_2022-03-10_16-42-39.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\giphy.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_0080.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_0835.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_1362.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_4698.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_4962.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_6359.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_7497.MOV", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_7909.MOV", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_9540.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\mp4.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\video.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\комочек тьмы.mp4", "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\кот.mp4"]

video = open(shit[random.randint(0, len(shit)-1)], 'rb')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start_message(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hello message 1')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['haha'])

def haha_message(message):

    while True:

            bot.send_video(message.chat.id, vidos)

            time.sleep(3600) #1 hour

@bot.message_handler(commands=['hehe'])

def shit_message(message):

bot.send_video(message.chat.id, vidos)   

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Also i dont understand error cause i dont close file only open

Comment: simpler `open(  random.choice(shit)  , 'rb')`

Comment: error suggests that file is empty - so first you should check sizes and what you have in file. You could check size manually in file manager. You could open in video player to check if it can be displayed. Eventually you could use  `os.stat(path).st_size` to get its size in code.

Comment: after sending file it may have pointer at the end of file and you should reopen it - to move to the beginning of file. OR you should use `.seek(0)` to move to the beginning of file.

Comment: if you want to send random file then you should rather use `random` inside loop. At this moment it select file only once  and later it try to send always the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem can be because you open file only once and you never close it and open again.

When it reads then it move special pointer which shows where to read next time. When it reads to the end of file then this pointer is moved to the end of file and when it tries to read again then it trires to read from the end of file and there is nothing to read and it may say that you have empty file.

After reading you may have to use `vidoe.seek(0)` to move pointer to the beginnig of file.

Or you should `close` and `open` it again. And this can be even more useful because at this moment you select random file only once and later it would use always the same path. You should use `random` inside loop.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['haha'])
def haha_message(message):

    while True:

        video = open( random.choice(shit), 'rb')
    
        bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video)
    
        video.close()
        
        time.sleep(3600)  # 1 hour
```

and the same in other functions

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['hehe'])
def shit_message(message):

    video = open( random.choice(shit), 'rb')

    bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video)   

    video.close()
```

---

**BTW:**

`telegram` may has some methods to execute tasks periodically.

For example module `python-telegram-bot` has [telegram.ext.jobqueue](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html) for this.

---

Full working code

For tests I set `logging.DEBUG` to see all error messages.
Normally `telebot` catchs all errors and hides them.

I also used `with open() as video` so it automatically closes file.

```
import os
import random
import logging
import telebot

# display errors 
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 

TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

all_videos = [
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\3wZ3.gif.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\65216814_456719028224290_7745639790787166208_n.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\doc_2022-03-10_16-41-49.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\doc_2022-03-10_16-42-04.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\doc_2022-03-10_16-42-39.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\giphy.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_0080.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_0835.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_1362.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_4698.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_4962.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_6359.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_7497.MOV",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_7909.MOV",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\IMG_9540.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\mp4.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\video.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\комочек тьмы.mp4",
    "C:\\Users\\glebc\\Documents\\source(bot)\\кот.mp4"
]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'hello message 1')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['haha'])
def haha_message(message):
    while True:
        with open(random.choice(all_videos), 'rb') as video:
            bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video)
        time.sleep(3600)  # 1 hour

@bot.message_handler(commands=['hehe'])
def shit_message(message):
    with open(random.choice(all_videos), 'rb') as video:
        bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video)   

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: One should note that the mentioned `JobQueue` is a class from the `python-telegram-bot` library, not the library `pyTelegramBotAPI` which is used here

Comment: @CallMeStag good point. There are many different modules and sometimes it can mess in head ;) I added details to answer.